# Zabbix и проверка доступности авторизации на сайте

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, zabbix

Подскажите, как сделать проверку доступности авторизации на сайте.

Т.е. что-бы Zabbix пытался авторизоваться и если не получалось, то срабатывал триггер например (ну триггер я могу сделать :D )

Как это вижу я:

**Пока были такие мысли:**
Указать Заббиксу слово которое есть только после авторизации в теле HTML
Но как заставить его авторизоваться ?
На сайте используется доменная авторизация.
А так-же есть возможность авторизации по базе пользователей 1С (не доменная).

Структура примерно такая:
Само веб приложение написано на Angular'e

Процедура  авторизации такая:
Есть форма для авторизации:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" ng-submit="enter(loginData)">

<img src="/img/logo.png" class="img-card img-rounded">
<input ng-model="loginData.username" ng-show="loaded" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя" required="" autofocus="">
 <input ng-model="loginData.password" placeholder="Пароль" ng-show="loaded" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" у required="">
 <div class="center"><select class="form-control btn-secondary" required id="dep0" style="cursor: pointer; ">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Выбрать предприятие</option>
 <option value="1">1</option> 
 <option value="2">2</option>  
 <option value="2">3</option> 
 <option value="none">Без предприятия</option> 
 </select>
 </div>
 <div class="text-center mgb-20" ng-hide="loaded">
 <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>
 </div>    
 <br><br>
 <button type="submit" ng-show="loaded" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Вход</button>
 </form>
```

Данные с этой формы идут вот в эту функцию:

```
  e.enter = function(e) {
            var varlog;
            if ($("#dep0").val()== "none")
                {

                varlog="";
            }

            else {

            varlog = $("#dep0").val();
            }

            t({ 
                method: "POST",
                url: o.url("api") + "/oauth?format=json",
                withCredentials: !0,
                data: {
                    UserName: varlog+e.username,
                    Password: e.password
                }
```

Т.е за хранение логина, пароля отвечают переменные **UserName** и **Password**
А Заббиксе можно делать POST запрос и я думаю, что это надо использовать. Но как правильно это сделать ?

Буду рад, если подскажите в какую сторону копать это все.

Наверное это очень тупой вопрос. Но ведь надо как-то учиться.

И да гуглил. Но что-то ответа как такого не нашел.

Comment: Это нормальный вопрос : ]  А официальная документация не помогла https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/web_monitoring/example ?

Comment: @a-k  сделал как написано в мануле :)  в качестве POST данных сделал так: UserName=*****&Password=*******&enter=Sign эти переменные в js на сайте хранят в себе логин и пароль. Но вот, в чем дело. Указываю верный логин/ пароль Заббикс не ругается, указываю не верный тоже не ругается я что-то не понял)

Comment: Мое мнение: если у вас форма авторизации привязана к javascript-у, то стандартными штуками заббикса это не получится, т.к. они реализованы на обычном cURL, а он таки не браузер.

Comment: @defrag да верно, я тоже почитал об этом. хмм, а не могли бы подсказать как это победить? –

Comment: паблик предлагает использовать Node.js (или похожее). Пишите собственный скрипт на нем, прикручиваете к заббиксу, настраиваете триггер. Как-то так.